# How do I copy a range of data and add it to another workbook at the end of that data?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub copy()
    Range(“A2:E30”).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode =False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("yGL dcs.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A47").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End sub
```

The first range is not always 29 rows and could be a different row in the yGL workbook. How do I make it be able to copy the data to the last row and add it to the last row of data in the yGL workbook? Thank you

Comment: You need to provide some more information about the dataset you're working with.  If it's not always 29 rows, how can that be determined?  Screenshots always help.

Comment: It could be from A2:E15 or it could be from A2:E65. It is a report that could vary from week to week.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit to pick apart with what you're trying to do and although using `.Select` or `.Activate` is not recommended (I think you may have just recorded a macro, which is more than ok), I'm not going to sit here and rewrite your entire solution because I simply don't have the time.

The following should help you though.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:" & ActiveSheet.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Address).Select
```

... that will help you select all of the data in your dynamic source workbook.  It'll select a range from A2 to the last row in column E dynamically.

And this piece of code ...

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Select
```

... will take you to the last row in your destination workbook in column A.

I hope that helps and I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I need it only to copy to column E as that code will copy all the way to the last column of data. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Djhans26, yep, answer updated.  If it works for you, be sure to flag it as the answer.  Thanks

Comment: @Djhans26, actually, I just realised, if that worksheet has a whole heap of other stuff in it then there is a chance that my approach, although only selecting up to column E, may select far too many rows.  You'll have to let me know.

Comment: It’s only a problem if the extra rows it selects contain data that you’re not wanting.

Comment: Yes, the worksheet has other data in it that I don’t need but I can’t just delete the columns that have other data in it.

Comment: @Djhans26 try with the latest edit.  Without seeing your data set, I'm punching in the dark.